# Media Foundation webcam video H264 encode/decode produces artifacts when played back

Tags: c++, h.264, ms-media-foundation, artifacts

I have a solution, where I encode video (YUY2) samples from a webcam with Media Foundation's h264 encoder. Then I send it via TCP connection to another application that decodes the stream with Media Foundation's h264 decoder back to YUY2 format. After decoding, the video samples/images are presented at the screen using DirectX.

The problem is that between key-frames the video image gets increasing amount of artifacts. Artifacts disappear when a key-frame is received.

I dropped the TCP connection out of the scope and did the decoding immediately after the encode, but still I have the artifacts bothering me.

Here's the callback method that receives the samples from the webcam:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// OnReadSample
//
// Called when the IMFMediaSource::ReadSample method completes.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

HRESULT CPreview::OnReadSample(
    HRESULT hrStatus,
    DWORD /* dwStreamIndex */,
    DWORD dwStreamFlags,
    LONGLONG llTimestamp,
    IMFSample *pSample      // Can be NULL
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

    EnterCriticalSection(&m_critsec);

    if (FAILED(hrStatus))
    {
        hr = hrStatus;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (pSample)
        {
            IMFSample *pEncodedSample = NULL;
            hr = m_pCodec->EncodeSample(pSample, &pEncodedSample);
            if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT || pEncodedSample == NULL)
            {
                hr = m_pReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
                return S_OK;
            }

            LONGLONG llEncodedSampleTimeStamp = 0;
            LONGLONG llEncodedSampleDuration = 0;
            pEncodedSample->GetSampleTime(&llEncodedSampleTimeStamp);
            pEncodedSample->GetSampleDuration(&llEncodedSampleDuration);

            pBuffer = NULL;
            hr = pEncodedSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &pBuffer);
            if (hr != S_OK)
            {
                hr = m_pReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
                return hr;
            }

            BYTE *pOutBuffer = NULL;
            DWORD dwMaxLength, dwCurrentLength;
            hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pOutBuffer, &dwMaxLength, &dwCurrentLength);
            if (hr != S_OK)
            {
                hr = m_pReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
                return hr;
            }
            // Send encoded webcam data to connected clients
            //SendData(pOutBuffer, dwCurrentLength, llEncodedSampleTimeStamp, llEncodedSampleDuration);

            pBuffer->Unlock();
            SafeRelease(&pBuffer);

            IMFSample *pDecodedSample = NULL;           
            m_pCodec->DecodeSample(pEncodedSample, &pDecodedSample);
            if (pDecodedSample != NULL)
            {
                pDecodedSample->SetSampleTime(llTimestamp);
                pDecodedSample->SetSampleTime(llTimestamp - llLastSampleTimeStamp);
                llLastSampleTimeStamp = llTimestamp;
                hr = pDecodedSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &pBuffer);
                //hr = pSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &pBuffer);

                // Draw the frame.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = m_draw.DrawFrame(pBuffer);
                }
                SafeRelease(&pDecodedSample);
            }

            SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
            SafeRelease(&pEncodedSample);           
        }
    }

    // Request the next frame.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            0,
            NULL,   // actual
            NULL,   // flags
            NULL,   // timestamp
            NULL    // sample
            );
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        NotifyError(hr);
    }
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
    return hr;
}
```

And here's the encoder/decoder initialization code:

```
    HRESULT Codec::InitializeEncoder()
    {   
        IMFMediaType *pMFTInputMediaType = NULL, *pMFTOutputMediaType = NULL;
        IUnknown *spTransformUnk = NULL;    
        DWORD mftStatus = 0;
        UINT8 blob[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0xc0, 0x1e, 0x96, 0x54, 0x05, 0x01,
            0xe9, 0x80, 0x80, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xce, 0x3c, 0x80 };

        CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
        MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

        // Create H.264 encoder.
        CHECK_HR(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMSH264EncoderMFT, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (void**)&spTransformUnk), "Failed to create H264 encoder MFT.\n");

        CHECK_HR(spTransformUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEncoderTransform)), "Failed to get IMFTransform interface from H264 encoder MFT object.\n");

        // Transform output type
        MFCreateMediaType(&pMFTOutputMediaType);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 500000);
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480), "Failed to set frame size on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1), "Failed to set frame rate on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set aspect ratio on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_MixedInterlaceOrProgressive);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);

        // Special attributes for H264 transform, if needed
        /*CHECK_HR(pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Base), "Failed to set profile on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_LEVEL, eAVEncH264VLevel4), "Failed to set level on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MAX_KEYFRAME_SPACING, 10), "Failed to set key frame interval on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, 100), "Failed to set H264 codec qulaity.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize, 1), "Failed to set CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize = 1\n");*/
        CHECK_HR(pEncoderTransform->SetOutputType(0, pMFTOutputMediaType, 0), "Failed to set output media type on H.264 encoder MFT.\n");

        // Transform input type
        MFCreateMediaType(&pMFTInputMediaType);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_YUY2);
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480), "Failed to set frame size on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1), "Failed to set frame rate on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set aspect ratio on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pEncoderTransform->SetInputType(0, pMFTInputMediaType, 0), "Failed to set input media type on H.264 encoder MFT.\n");

        CHECK_HR(pEncoderTransform->GetInputStatus(0, &mftStatus), "Failed to get input status from H.264 MFT.\n");
        if (MFT_INPUT_STATUS_ACCEPT_DATA != mftStatus)
        {
            printf("E: pEncoderTransform->GetInputStatus() not accept data.\n");
            goto done;
        }

        CHECK_HR(pEncoderTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, NULL), "Failed to process FLUSH command on H.264 MFT.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pEncoderTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL), "Failed to process BEGIN_STREAMING command on H.264 MFT.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pEncoderTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM, NULL), "Failed to process START_OF_STREAM command on H.264 MFT.\n");

        return S_OK;

    done:

        SafeRelease(&pMFTInputMediaType);
        SafeRelease(&pMFTOutputMediaType);

        return S_FALSE;
    }

    HRESULT Codec::InitializeDecoder()
    {
        IUnknown *spTransformUnk = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *pMFTOutputMediaType = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *pMFTInputMediaType = NULL;
        DWORD mftStatus = 0;

        // Create H.264 decoder.
        CHECK_HR(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMSH264DecoderMFT, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (void**)&spTransformUnk), "Failed to create H264 decoder MFT.\n");

        // Query for the IMFTransform interface 
        CHECK_HR(spTransformUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDecoderTransform)), "Failed to get IMFTransform interface from H264 decoder MFT object.\n");

        // Create input mediatype for the decoder
        MFCreateMediaType(&pMFTInputMediaType);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480), "Failed to set frame size on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1), "Failed to set frame rate on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set aspect ratio on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_MixedInterlaceOrProgressive);
        pMFTInputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);
        CHECK_HR(pDecoderTransform->SetInputType(0, pMFTInputMediaType, 0), "Failed to set input media type on H.264 encoder MFT.\n");

        CHECK_HR(pDecoderTransform->GetInputStatus(0, &mftStatus), "Failed to get input status from H.264 MFT.\n");
        if (MFT_INPUT_STATUS_ACCEPT_DATA != mftStatus)
        {
            printf("E: pDecoderTransform->GetInputStatus() not accept data.\n");
            goto done;
        }

        // Create outmedia type for the decoder
        MFCreateMediaType(&pMFTOutputMediaType);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
        pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_YUY2);
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480), "Failed to set frame size on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1), "Failed to set frame rate on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1), "Failed to set aspect ratio on H264 MFT out type.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pDecoderTransform->SetOutputType(0, pMFTOutputMediaType, 0), "Failed to set output media type on H.264 decoder MFT.\n");

        CHECK_HR(pDecoderTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, NULL), "Failed to process FLUSH command on H.264 MFT.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pDecoderTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL), "Failed to process BEGIN_STREAMING command on H.264 MFT.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pDecoderTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM, NULL), "Failed to process START_OF_STREAM command on H.264 MFT.\n");

        return S_OK;

    done:

        SafeRelease(&pMFTInputMediaType);
        SafeRelease(&pMFTOutputMediaType);

        return S_FALSE;
    }
```

Here's the actual decode/encoder part:

```
HRESULT Codec::EncodeSample(IMFSample *pSample, IMFSample **ppEncodedSample)
{
    return TransformSample(pEncoderTransform, pSample, ppEncodedSample);
}

HRESULT Codec::DecodeSample(IMFSample *pSample, IMFSample **ppEncodedSample)
{
    return TransformSample(pDecoderTransform, pSample, ppEncodedSample);
}

HRESULT Codec::TransformSample(IMFTransform *pTransform, IMFSample *pSample, IMFSample **ppSampleOut)
{
    IMFSample *pOutSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD mftOutFlags;
    pTransform->ProcessInput(0, pSample, 0);
    CHECK_HR(pTransform->GetOutputStatus(&mftOutFlags), "H264 MFT GetOutputStatus failed.\n");

    // Note: Decoder does not return MFT flag MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY, so we just need to rely on S_OK return
    if (pTransform == pEncoderTransform && mftOutFlags == S_OK)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
    else if (pTransform == pEncoderTransform && mftOutFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STATUS_SAMPLE_READY ||
        pTransform == pDecoderTransform && mftOutFlags == S_OK)
    {
        DWORD processOutputStatus = 0;
        MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outputDataBuffer;
        MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO StreamInfo;
        pTransform->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &StreamInfo);

        CHECK_HR(MFCreateSample(&pOutSample), "Failed to create MF sample.\n");
        CHECK_HR(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(StreamInfo.cbSize, &pBuffer), "Failed to create memory buffer.\n");
        if (pTransform == pEncoderTransform)
            CHECK_HR(pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(StreamInfo.cbSize), "Failed SetCurrentLength.\n");
        CHECK_HR(pOutSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer), "Failed to add sample to buffer.\n");      
        outputDataBuffer.dwStreamID = 0;
        outputDataBuffer.dwStatus = 0;
        outputDataBuffer.pEvents = NULL;
        outputDataBuffer.pSample = pOutSample;

        HRESULT hr = pTransform->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outputDataBuffer, &processOutputStatus);
        if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT)
        {
            SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
            SafeRelease(&pOutSample);
            return hr;
        }

        LONGLONG llVideoTimeStamp, llSampleDuration;
        pSample->GetSampleTime(&llVideoTimeStamp);
        pSample->GetSampleDuration(&llSampleDuration);
        CHECK_HR(outputDataBuffer.pSample->SetSampleTime(llVideoTimeStamp), "Error setting MFT sample time.\n");
        CHECK_HR(outputDataBuffer.pSample->SetSampleDuration(llSampleDuration), "Error setting MFT sample duration.\n");        
        if (pTransform == pEncoderTransform)
        {
            IMFMediaBuffer *pMediaBuffer = NULL;
            DWORD dwBufLength;
            CHECK_HR(pOutSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pMediaBuffer), "ConvertToContiguousBuffer failed.\n");
            CHECK_HR(pMediaBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&dwBufLength), "Get buffer length failed.\n");

            WCHAR *strDebug = new WCHAR[256];
            wsprintf(strDebug, L"Encoded sample ready: time %I64d, sample duration %I64d, sample size %i.\n", llVideoTimeStamp, llSampleDuration, dwBufLength);
            OutputDebugString(strDebug);
            SafeRelease(&pMediaBuffer);
        }
        else if (pTransform == pDecoderTransform)
        {
            IMFMediaBuffer *pMediaBuffer = NULL;
            DWORD dwBufLength;
            CHECK_HR(pOutSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pMediaBuffer), "ConvertToContiguousBuffer failed.\n");
            CHECK_HR(pMediaBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&dwBufLength), "Get buffer length failed.\n");

            WCHAR *strDebug = new WCHAR[256];
            wsprintf(strDebug, L"Decoded sample ready: time %I64d, sample duration %I64d, sample size %i.\n", llVideoTimeStamp, llSampleDuration, dwBufLength);
            OutputDebugString(strDebug);
            SafeRelease(&pMediaBuffer);
        }

        // Decoded sample out
        *ppSampleOut = pOutSample;

        //SafeRelease(&pMediaBuffer);
        SafeRelease(&pBuffer);

        return S_OK;
    }

done:
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
    SafeRelease(&pOutSample);

    return S_FALSE;
}
```

I've searched solution for this for a quite a while now and found one question that is defined quite similarly as my issue, but as it was for a different API, it was no help to me. [FFMPEG decoding artifacts between keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844529/ffmpeg-decoding-artifacts-between-keyframes)

Best Regards,
Toni Riikonen

Comment: I noticed that, if I wait for about 30-60 seconds after the stream has started, the artifacts disappeared. Could this be somekind of buffering issue, or should I buffer the samples a bit before letting decoder get hold of them.

Or is there something wrong with my timestamps?

Comment: pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 500000); 500kbps is a too low value for the bitrate. The encoding quality will be bad in this case and will result in artifacts. Try with 5000000 (5Mbps) instead, or even higher value.

Comment: Have tried larger bitrates, the artifacts gets smaller in size, but does not disappear. I'm not talking about the usual artifacts caused by the lossy encoding algorithm but artifacts that seems to me like it is dropping data or the samples are out of order.

Is it possible that in the OnReadSample callback method, as I need multiple input samples for the first encoded sample, the IMFSamples that are passed to this callback function are released? I was thinking maybe making a copy of the samples provided be the callback function then releasing them after I'm done with them.

Comment: The IMFSample returned in OnReadSample is released after the function exits. If you need to keep the sample, you have to AddRef it and put it in a queue for instance.

Comment: Did make a copy of the samples provided by the callback function and did queue them and then released them after I was done with them. However, this did not change anything - still having artifacts for the 30-60 seconds from the start of the stream.

What bothers me is that the artifacts does really end if the stream is on for 30-60 seconds, after that, no artifacts appear. But I need the stream to be healthy from the get-go.

Comment: It still sounds to me like quality/bitrate problem. I can suggest: 
1. Since you are creating the H264 encoder yourself, you can query it for ICodecAPI and try different settings. Namely, CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, CODECAPI_AVEncAdaptiveMode, CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed, CODECAPI_AVEncVideoEncodeQP. 
2. You might also try creating a hardware H264 encoder and use IMFDXGIDeviceManager with it (Windows 8 and above?)
3. I also noticed that you decode the sample after OnReadSample. The reader should provide decoded samples already. No need to decode.

Comment: By increasing the bitrate and experimenting with the CODECAPI values you provided, I get the artifacts lower in quantity. Not still perfect, but could be something I can live with. Should look into the hardware encoder as well to release the burden from the CPU.

I will mark your answer as the correct one, but might need to revisit this at some point.

Comment: @ Toni Riikonen Thanks, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little late to the game here but I can confirm that the answer from Homepage is the correct solution. I also encountered this same problem but I was only using the decoder portion of this sample code. I was reading in an MP4 file and saw the increasing artifacts between key frames. As soon as I received a key frame, the image looked good and then progressively got worse. Here is the code I added within the Codec::InitializeDecoder():

```
// Set CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode
ICodecAPI *mpCodecAPI = NULL;
hr = pDecoderTransform->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mpCodecAPI));
CHECK_HR(hr, "Failed to get ICodecAPI.\n");

VARIANT var;
var.vt = VT_BOOL;
var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode, &var);
CHECK_HR(hr, "Failed to enable low latency mode.\n");
```

After I added these changes the program worked much better! Thanks to this software on GitHub for giving me the necessary code:
https://github.com/GameTechDev/ChatHeads/blob/master/VideoStreaming/EncodeTransform.cpp

Comment: Good to hear that this will resolve the problem in Windows 8 and up. Sadly we are still supporting Windows 7 where this LowLatencyMode option is not available. Most probably we will drop the support for Windows 7 soon, so this solution is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like quality/bitrate problem.

```
pMFTOutputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 500000);
```

500kbps is a too low value for the bitrate, you may try with something bigger like 5, 10 or 20Mbps.

I can suggest:

1. Since you are creating the H264 encoder yourself, you can query it for ICodecAPI and try different settings. Namely, CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, CODECAPI_AVEncAdaptiveMode, CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed, CODECAPI_AVEncVideoEncodeQP.
2. You might also try creating a hardware H264 encoder and use IMFDXGIDeviceManager with it (Windows 8 and above?)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to have the answer but I still want to share my experience. Hope that can help who met the similar issue.

I also encountered the similar artifacts problem while decoding H264. However, in my case, the stream is from video capture device, and the artifacts do not disappear after 30-60 seconds from the start of the stream.

In my opinion, I guess the decoder with normal setting cannot decode the live streaming due to the low- latency. Thus, I try to enable the CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode which can set decode/encode mode to Low-latency for real-time communications or live capture. (To get more details, please refer the following link from MS
https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/hh447590(v=vs.85).aspx
) Fortunately, the problem has been solved and the decoder work normally.

Although there is a bit different of our problem, you can try to enable/disable CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode in your case, and I hope you can also have good news.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an IP(B) frame ordering problem.

Encoded frame order is not the same as decoded frame order. I did not test your code, but i think that the encoder provides frame in encoded order and that you need to reorder frame before rendering.

Comment: It seems that even using the Microsoft API samples and saving as MP4 the artifacts are still present. So I'm guessing that whether Microsoft's H264 encoder/decoder is bad at handling noise on the webcam image (as most cheap webcam's produce noisy image) or the encoder/decoder is somewhat broken.

I have decided to switch to use WMV3 instead. Not sure which answer would be the correct answer, as the actual problem is not fully solved and might be kind of issue that is out of developer hands.